nodejs rewrite file segment
In nodejs, how do I overwrite a section of a file without creating additional files or reading all the data into memory?
let filename= '123.txt';
const fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'w+');
fs.writeSync(fd, Buffer.from('123'), 0, 3, 5);
fs.closeSync(fd);

This code is expected to overwrite 3 bytes of the file starting from 6, but it completely erases the contents and inserts 5 null bytes at the beginning, if you set the a+ flag, it always writes to the end of the file.

I only know C++ can do this because it has seekp. But in Nods.js, you must read it to a Buffer and slice it.

Mainly you'd want to use r+ flag instead of w+.
There are already answers present to similar questions , you can reference them or even refer to docs for further information.
